# Cerrar contenedor presionando un botón

Tags: javascript, html, css, botón

Tengo un botón que abre un contenedor al darle clic, y me cierra dicho contenedor al darle en cualquier parte de la pantalla, excepto cuando presiono dentro del contenedor.

Tengo dos problemas los cuales no consigo solucionar:

1- Intento que el botón aparezca encima del contenedor con z-index, pero siempre aparece detrás del contener, y así no puedo volver a dar para cerrar.

2- Aunque el botón está detrás del contenedor, cuando consigo darle, no cierra el contenedor. Me gustaría poder cerrar el contenedor dándole al botón.

```
<div id="box1">
  <h2>Popup</h2>
</div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('box1').style.display='block'" id="btn-menu">button</button>


<style>
    #box1{
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 260px;
        height: 260px;
        background: #E2E2E2;
        padding: 20px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #btn-menu{
      z-index: 9;
    }
</style>

<script>
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
          var box = document.getElementById('box1');
          if(event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box){
            box.style.display = 'none';
          }
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: ¿Y si lo pones dentro?  Pero pon dentro un boton de cierre, pues el que quieres mostrar sobre el popup es para abrirlo solamente.  Mira aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/fz9Lmyxu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo agregaría una clase visible con la propiedad display: block y dejaría esta propiedad en none por defecto. Y luego agregaría un evento al botón para que alterne esta clase:

```
<div id="box1">
  <h2>Popup</h2>
</div>
<button onclick="toggle()" id="btn-menu">button</button>
<style>
    #box1{
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 260px;
        height: 260px;
        background: #E2E2E2;
        padding: 20px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
#box1.visible{
display: block
}
    #btn-menu{
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9;
    }
</style> 
<script>
window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  var box = document.getElementById('box1');
  if(event.target != box && event.target.id != 'btn-menu' && event.target.parentNode != box){
    console.log(event.target);
    box.classList.remove('visible');
  }
});

function toggle(){
   var box = document.getElementById('box1');
   box.classList.toggle('visible');
}
```

Ahora abre con el botón, cierra al pulsar el botón o fuera del bloque. Y no actúa cuando pulsas dentro del bloque.